# sum query with distinct columns

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

this is my table batchmaster with columns like batchname,subbatchname,records

```
BatchName    SubBatch   records     
12032014     raw1_0     2  
12032014     raw1_0     2  
12032014     raw1_1     2  
12032014     raw1_1     2     
12302014     raw7_0    150  
12302014     raw7_0    150
```

I want to get output like with distinct batchname,subbatch and sum of records for distinct subbatch.

```
BatchName    SubBatch   records  
12032014     raw1_0     4  
12032014     raw1_1     4 
12302014     raw7_0   300
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would really help if you would put a bit more time into giving us some context, and formatting the results more clearly. What are the columns here? How do you expect to get those results? It looks like for raw_10 and raw_1_1 you're adding up the last column... but then you're not doing that for the raw7_0 result... What have you tried in order to get your desired result?

Comment: Are you sure you input or outputs are correctly defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT BatchName,SubBatch,SUM(records) AS Records
    FROM urTableName
  GROUP BY BatchName, SubBatch
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work for you

```
SELECT BatchName,SubBatch,SUM(records) AS SumRecords
FROM batchmaster
GROUP BY BatchName, SubBatch
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Conrad Lotz query.

Try this

```
DECLARE @batch_master TABLE
  (
     BatchName VARCHAR(50),
     SubBatch  VARCHAR(50),
     records   INT
  )

INSERT INTO @batch_master
VALUES      ('12032014',
             'raw1_0',
             '2'),
            ('12032014',
             'raw1_0',
             '2'),
            ('12032014',
             'raw1_1',
             '2'),
            ('12032014',
             'raw1_1',
             '2'),
            ('12302014',
             'raw7_0',
             '150'),
            ('12302014',
             'raw7_0',
             '150')

SELECT *
FROM   @batch_master

SELECT batchname,
       subbatch,
       sum(records)
FROM   @batch_master
GROUP  BY batchname,
          subbatch
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT BatchName,SubBatch,SUM(records) AS Records
FROM Table
GROUP BY BatchName, SubBatch
```